# Django error: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with no arguments not found

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.11 to build an user account application. My urls for my account app is as Code 1 as below. And also I have a templates/registrations folder and several template files there:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU8IU.png)

After I input the email address and I receive the email with the following link:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password-reset/confirm/MQ/4ra-66d3672f1d340589fbf9/

I click the above link and the browser redirects to this link:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password-reset/confirm/MQ/set-password/

And the error prompts:

NoReverseMatch at /account/password-reset/confirm/MQ/set-password/

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/password-reset/confirm/(?P[-\w]+)/(?P[-\w]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password-reset/confirm/MQ/set-password/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/password-reset/confirm/(?P[-\w]+)/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

Please help me how to solve this problem. It seems that after I click the link, the Django fails to render the password_reset_confirm.html under templates/registration folder.

Code 1:

```
    # restore password urls
    url(r'^password-reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password-reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>[-\w]+)/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the password reset confirm template file and get rid off the action on the form like this

```
<form   method="post"> </form>
```

instead of this :

```
<form   action={% url 'your template file name'%} method="post"></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Django's error message is saying that your code has tried to reverse `password_reset_confirm` to its url, but you haven't supplied the `uid64` and `token` arguments that the url pattern requires. You should locate the section of your code where you perform the `reverse()` and update it to supply the arguments:

```
reverse('password_reset_confirm',args=(uid64, token))
```

Comment: I have set the name "password_reset_confirm" for the url that Django can reverse the name to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

urls.py:

```
path('accounts/reset_password_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='reset_password_confirm'),
```

Changing URL as above worked for me. Although, I am still not getting email. The error disappeared.

Comment: this helped me but i need to add this route in main urls.py in order to work not accounts application

Answer (score -1):

```
path('users/password_reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='commons/password_reset_form.html',
    subject_template_name='commons/password_reset_subject.txt',
    email_template_name='commons/password_reset_email.html',
    success_url='done',), name="password_reset"),

path('users/password_reset/done/', 
    PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name='commons/password_reset_done.html'),name="password_reset_done"),

path('users/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='commons/password_reset_confirm.html',
    success_url='/users/reset/done/'),name="password_reset_confirm"),

path('users/reset/done/',
    PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='commons/password_reset_complete.html'),
    name="password_reset_complete"),
```